# Failed to deploy quickstart to Fabric8 on Jube

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm running Fabric8 2.1.5 version with Jube on my local Win7 PC, and trying to follow the documentation to deploy the Camel-Spring quickstart

When I run "mvn fabric8:deploy" under quickstarts/java/camel-spring folder, I got the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:2.1.5:deploy (default-cli) on project
>   quickstart-java-cam el-spring: Error executing: Failed to post App Zip
>   to: http://localhost:8585/hawtio/git/master/ HTTP/1.1 302 Found

I did try to put the URL http://localhost:8585/hawtio/git/master/ in browser, and it redirected me back to the hawtio console home page

Have I missed any config on my Fabric8 to make the deployment works?

Comment: Supplement: I download Fabric8 2.1.5 with Jube from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/jube/images/jube/jube/2.1.5/jube-2.1.5-image.zip) and follows the quickstart instructions [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/quickstarts/tree/project-2.1.5/quickstarts/java/camel-spring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately with recent bigger changes to upgrading to kubernetes
v1beta3 apis, and changes on the web console to use web sockets and we
are in process of upgrading jube to use hawtio v2 as the web console,
so it uses exactly the same web console as you would on a linux
platform with real kubernetes.

The bottom line is that current jube releases do not work out of the box.

It would be a while until we get all this sorted and working again.

The native linux / docker / kubernetes distribution of fabric8 works.